# How to read the value of a "child" inside a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase

I want to read the value of a child(name) from Client's nodes when I use a firebase recycler adapter from Request's nodes which have childs with the value of Client's keys

[image]

I tried this, but I only received the link

```
adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(optionsReq) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Request model) {

            holder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            holder.txtOrderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
            holder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
            holder.txtOrderDate.setText(Common.getDate(Long.parseLong(model.getDate())));
            holder.txtOrderClient.setText(client.child(model.getDniclient()).child("name").toString());

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_layout, parent,false);
            return new OrderViewHolder(view);
        }
    };


    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
String name;

adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(optionsReq) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Request model) {

        holder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());

        holder.txtOrderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
        holder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
        holder.txtOrderDate.setText(Common.getDate(Long.parseLong(model.getDate())));
        holder.txtOrderClient.setText(client.child(model.getDniclient()).child("name").toString());

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Client").child(model.getDniclient());

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_layout, parent,false);
            return new OrderViewHolder(view);
        }
    };


    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, although I thought there would be a way without having to implement a "ValueEvenListener" for a single value.